# Event Handling on Tree Last Node

Tags: swing, event-handling, jtree, treenode

Could you please tell me how can we do event Handling on Parent node of leaf.

Here I want to do event handling on RRITG04 Node.

```
mobileEnablerTxnListTree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent p_evt) {
    if (p_evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode l_selected_node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) mobileEnablerTxnListTree
            .getLastSelectedPathComponent();

        if (l_selected_node != null && l_selected_node.isRoot())
        meTxnListTreeRightClickNewEntity(p_evt);
        if (l_selected_node != null && l_selected_node.isLeaf())
        meTxnListTreeRightClick(p_evt);
    }
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: The same way as for every other node: by adding the appropriate event listener(s). You should elaborate a bit more if you want help: explain what you want to do, and show us what you've tried.

Comment: what do you mean by "do event handling"?

Comment: @kleopatra want to open a dialog box on clicking that particular node.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for useful comment.I just want to do the event handling on a particular node and the name of the node i have already specified in my question.Have updated question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent p_evt) {

    DefaultMutableTreeNode l_selected_node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) returnMobileEnablerFieldMapTree
        .getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    if (p_evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {


if (l_selected_node != null
            & l_selected_node.equals(l_selected_node
                .getLastLeaf().getParent())) {
           Do whatever you want ...........
}
}
```

I got resolved my problem by doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Please guide me, if this is not a good one way to find out the parent node of leaf.